# table into a table row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

> ```
> > Table 1 : Category :id   , Name          :1     Hardware 2     Software
> > 
> > Table2 Hardware : id   ,  Name           :1      Hard disck  .      . .      .
> > 
> > Table 3 Software :id   , Name            :1      Java .      . .      .
> ```

i have these tables in my database and i want to display categories ans by selecting categories the user can watch the other table , but i don't know what's the right way to do this !!  epspicially if the user can dynamically add new categories and how to create the new categories tables dynamically!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "watch"? And is your question about dynamically creating tables or about monitoring your set of tables?

Comment: i mean visualise by "watch" , yes i'm asking about dynamically create tables from a line in another table !!

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside mysql (using triggers? stored procedures?) or are you using another language to access mysql? If the latter, which one? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stop. Don't create tables for each category.** Use a proper schema design from the beginning. It will pay off big time by allowing you normally maintain and query your data.

In your case the schema might look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE categories
(
  category_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  category_name VARCHAR(128)
);

CREATE TABLE items
(
  item_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  category_id INT, 
  item_name VARCHAR(128),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (category_id)
);
```

To insert new items and associate them with categories

```
INSERT INTO items (category_id, item_name)
VALUES (1, 'Hard disk');
INSERT INTO items (category_id, item_name)
VALUES (2, 'Java');
```

To get items in category `Hardware`

```sql
SELECT item_id, item_name
  FROM items i JOIN categories c
    ON i.category_id = c.category_id
 WHERE c.category_name = 'Hardware'
```

or to easily get a count of items per category

```
SELECT category_name, COUNT(item_id) no_items
  FROM categories c LEFT JOIN items i
    ON c.category_id = i.category_id
 GROUP BY c.category_id, c.category_name;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30f85/2)** demo

If an item may belong to different categories then you'll need a many-to-many table `categories_items`.